# Centering the last column

Tags: tables

I have a problem centering the last column's cells. All columns are correctly centered except the last one!

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
    \caption{Group assessment} %POS
  \begin{tabular}{| p{3.3cm} | p{3.0cm}| p{3cm}| p{3cm}|}
    \hline
     \centering \textbf{ Group} &  \centering \textbf{ Team Size} &  \centering \textbf{Unstructured} & \textbf{Semi-Structured}  \\ \hline

      \centering Group A  &  \centering 5 &  \centering 1 &  4 \\ \hline
      \centering Group B  &  \centering 6 &  \centering 1 &  6 \\ \hline
      \centering Group C  &  \centering 5 &  \centering 1 &  5 \\ \hline
      \centering Group D  &  \centering 3 &  \centering 1 &  3 \\ \hline


  \end{tabular}
  \label{table:Group}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Comment: use `\centering\arraybackslash` (or use `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\ `)

Comment: That worked well!